# Generic key of and typescript autocomplete in nested object

Tags: typescript, generics, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, intellisense

I have code:

```
type User = {
  name:string;
  profile:Profile
}

type Profile =  {
  isActive:boolean;
}

type CustomType<T> = {
  userWithProfile: keyof T | any
}

const customType:CustomType<User> = { userWithProfile:"" }
```

With this example, intellisense not working on userWithProfile property. If I remove | any from definition, intellisense work, but work only in first object (User).

Is here any workaround, how setup keyof T in nested object?

I am using latest vscode (1.38.1) and typescript 3.6.2.

Thanks

Comment: what do you want `userWithProfile` to be? `name | profile | isActive` ?

Comment: "profile.isActive", This is example, in real usecase ,i try define GridColumn<T> with nested objects